# Can I see in which lists my Lookup Column is used?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I wanna know if there is a way to see, in which List one of my Lookup field is used while I am in that List? I wanna see "This Element is used in these lists: [Name of List]" ... Is there a way?

Greetings!

Comment: I don't think there are any SharePoint out of the box settings available to check if list column is used as lookup column in other lists.